# How to add menù section to my WordPress template?

Tags: content-management-system, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new in WordPress blog and I am developing a blog with this template:
http://scorejava.com/wordpress351

As you can see at the top of the page there is a "menù" that only show the page in the site (at this moment: "Home" and "Pagina di esempio").

This menù is showed by the following lines of code into the header.php file:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
```

So I think that this is not a true menù but only a list of the statics pages present on my blog.

If, in the administrator dashboard I go to the menù section in the "Position of themes" square say me that: **"This theme has no support for menus but it is possible use the personalized menu widget to add every created menu in the sidebar"**

So I think that my template have no definied a true menù section on the top (but only a list for the static pages). Can I add a true section where add a true menu? How can I do?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/91970. Andrea, please, read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function dasboard_menu() {  
    global $menu; 
    $menu[6] = array( __('Orders'), 'read', 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order', '', 'menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-orders', 'menu-dashboard', 'none' );
    $menu[7] = array( __('Catalogue'), 'read', 'edit.php?post_type=product', '', 'menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-catalogue', 'menu-dashboard', 'none' );
    $menu[8] = array( __('Coupons'), 'read', 'edit.php?post_type=shop_coupon', '', 'menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-coupon', 'menu-dashboard', 'none' );
}  
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'dasboard_sub_menu' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point is to register your menus in functions.php. Like this:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
'main_nav'=>__('Main','mythmeme'),
'footer_nav'=>__('Footer','mythmeme'),)
);
```

It's all in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus).

You then just need to call the menu in your header.php (or footer.php):

```
<nav>
<?php wp_nav_menu(
array('theme_location' => 'main_nav')
); ?>
</nav>
```

Once registered and called you can you use dashboard > appearance > menu to create and add menus to your theme locations.